# Unable to rename test object in katalon

Tags: katalon-studio

Unable to rename test object in katalon studio version 7
Also error appears while trying to copy from one object repository to another [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

It's beacuse there is already a file with desired name.
In my image example I have a TestObject called a_Home which I want to rename to FOO, but there already exist a file with this name (no matter if not appearing in Katalon UI). So I have to delete the FOO.rs file manualy first. Same for TestData files.
[image: err casuse]